# How to write multi line sql query (nodejs)

Tags: mysql, sql, ecmascript-6

How can I write the following query using template strings of es6?

```
connection.query('\
CREATE TABLE `' + dbconfig.database + '`.`' + dbconfig.users_table + '` ( \
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \
    `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, \
    `password` CHAR(60) NOT NULL, \
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`), \
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC), \
    UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) \
)');
```

Is there any other better way of writing multi line sql queries?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In ES6 you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as they're allowed to be multi-line.

```
connection.query(`CREATE TABLE ${dbconfig.database}.${dbconfig.users_table} ( 
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    password CHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE INDEX id_UNIQUE (id ASC), 
    UNIQUE INDEX username_UNIQUE (username ASC) 
)`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though template strings work as expected, I have hard time to read, validate and format the SQL queries put inside of them.

I prefer to have a utility function that loads a query as a string from a file on app start.

Here is a TypeScript example of this utility function:

```
import {existsSync, readFileSync} from 'fs'

export const loadQuery = (queryFileName: string) => {
    const path = `src/queries/${queryFileName}.sql`

    if (!existsSync(path)) {
        process.exit(1)
    }

    return readFileSync(path, 'utf8')
}
```

Now, I have an SQL file which I can autoformat with any tool I find handy:

```
SELECT
    article.title,
    article.description,
    article.created_by,
    article.company_id
FROM articles article
     INNER JOIN users usr ON
                          usr.company_id = article.company_id AND
                          usr.email = $1
ORDER BY article.title;
```

Which looks this way in WebStorm with an SQL formatting plugin installed:

[image: SQL formatted]

In the end, I call it this way (Koa/Express endpoint example):

```
import {dbClient} from '../dbClient'
import {loadQuery} from './loadQuery'

const getUserCompanyArticlesQuery = loadQuery('getUserCompanyArticles')

export const getUserCompanyArticles = async (email: string) => {
    const result = await dbClient.query(
        getUserCompanyArticlesQuery,
        [email])

    return result.rows
}
```

Pros:

1. Autoformatting of the SQL.
2. Separating SQL queries from the code which improves readability.
3. I can quickly see the query itself when I need to debug.

Cons:

1. You have to have and load an external file from the filesystem when
   running the app.

Comment: this will cause a huge I/O ... and it might get a messy quickly.. this is definitely not a good practice.. sorry but -1

Comment: "Separating SQL queries from the code which improves readability." I disagree on that. SQL queries can be a part of the business logic as much as the rest of the controller code. If you want conciseness a DAO is a better option.